# What type Client ID needed for custom hardware with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, hardware-interface

I have a little background with Google Cloud Endpoints on App Engine and the Web Application, iOS and Android Client Id's.  However we are now building a custom piece of hardware.  It will be a gateway that is connected directly to a modem, accepts some data from various sources (sensors) and relays that information to App Engine.

Since this is not a web application, nor a iOS or Android app, would I use the "other" client ID option in the Credentials for my GCE project?  And if so, could someone explain how to communicate with this "other" client id to a generic cloud endpoint address (a curl command would be great since I could follow that easily).

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Oh, and the language used on the gateway is not known yet, but if anyone had any kind of example in any language just so I could see and understand that would be great.  Thanks

Comment: Hello, I'm Mario and a representative of Google Cloud Platform. Were you able to solve this issue or not? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Mario.  I have been in contact with you team & have this solved thank you

Comment: Good to hear that. Do you mind sharing it here so that the whole community can benefit? Thanks.